# How do I center the counter in IE7?

Tags: html

Have a look at the link below. Works fine in all other browsers but not IE7.

http://www.sonnyt.com/countie/

Now go to this site and paste the link into the box to see how it views in IE7

http://netrenderer.com/index.php

Any ideas how to make it work in all?

Just the counter element that I need to be centered.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code that you have tried to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a width to `#countdown` and then set the left and right margins to `auto`. Chrome reports the counter width to be 697px, so this should work:

```
#countdown {
    width: 697px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`display: inline-block` only works on elements with natural `display: inline` in IE7](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html).  There are several possible solutions, but I'll give two:

1. Remove `float: left` from `<li>` elements and use `display: inline` instead, plus `margin: 0 auto` on the `<ul>` (which must be `display: block`).
2. Stop supporting IE7